# How to embed a Mongoid tree in another document?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I'm using [mongoid-tree](https://github.com/benedikt/mongoid-tree) but this question probably applies to other [acts_as_tree ports for Mongoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753939/recommendations-on-structure-for-mongoid-mongodb-tree-of-tags).

I want a tree of nodes and I want the whole tree to be embedded in another document. My problem is that this really only requires that the root node be embedded but all nodes have the same embedded_in. In my case:

```
class Container
  include Mongoid::Document

  embeds_one :root, :class_name => "Node"
end

class Node
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Tree

  embedded_in :container, :inverse_of => :root
end
```

How can I set this up so that only one record per tree is embedded_in the Container? Is there another approach that would be better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author of mongoid-tree, [benedikt](https://github.com/benedikt), answered on GitHub.

Currently Mongoid::Tree doesn't work with embedded Nodes. He suggests:

```
class Container
  include Mongoid::Document

  referenced_in :node, :inverse_of => :container
end

class Node
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Tree

  references_one :container
end
```

This way you any node can be assigned to a container. You could also overwrite the Node.container method to call root.container for child nodes so you'd get the container for subnodes as well.